# Ruby mixin class methods

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to provide a class attribute setter and getter via a mixin, but clearly I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

This code results in the error `mod.rb:16:in '<class:Klass>': undefined method 'set_n' for Klass:Class (NoMethodError)`:

```
module Mixin
  @@n = 0

  def self.set_n(n)
    @@n = n
  end

  def self.get_n
    @@n
  end
end


class Klass
  include Mixin
  set_n 100
end


n = Klass.get_n
```

Little help?

Comment: Try using `extend` instead of `include`.

Comment: Module methods (`def self.set_n...end`) cannot be mixed in. They are simply helper methods that are invoked on the method (e.g., `Math.sqrt(5)`). If a module is `include`d by a class the former's instance methods (e.g., `def set_n...end`) become instance methods for the class; If a module is `extend`ed by a class the former's instance methods (e.g., `def set_n...end`) become class methods for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rewrite the module using instance methods and instance variables, i.e.:

```
module Mixin
  def set_n(n)
    @n = n
  end

  def get_n
    @n ||= 0
  end
end
```

The above can then be added to your class via `extend`:

```
class Klass
  extend Mixin

  set_n 100
end

Klass.get_n #=> 100
```

Note that `get_` and `set_` prefixes are quite unidiomatic in Ruby. You typically use the attribute's name as the getter and append a `=` for the setter.

Comment: Seems a bit counter-intuitive (and wasteful?) to create an instance variable that will be the same in each instance, but looks like it might be the only way to implement this for mixins. Good point regarding `get_` and `set_`

Comment: @Benjineer it adds a so-called _class instance variable_ which is an instance variable on to the class object itself (not to its instances). In Ruby, classes are objects (and therefore instances) too. We take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cary Swoveland mentioned, module methods can't be mixed in so I'll need to implement a base class:

```
class BaseClass
  @@n = 0

  def self.set_n(n)
    @@n = n
  end

  def self.get_n
    @@n
  end
end


class Klass < BaseClass
  set_n 100
end


n = Klass.get_n
```

This works as intended, but I won't be able to use it in a multiple inheritance scenario (hopefully won't be required).